Did Tsunade like Jiraiya?
I would like to know if Tsunade loved Jiraiya. Did she have feelings for Jiraiya?

I really don't think she's in love with Jiraiya. As it was revealed on this episode, Tsunade was in love with Dan Kato even after he died. So Tsunade only likes Jiraiya as a friend.
However, she was very sad when Jiraiya died.
